# RuntimeError: Failed to shutdown the live test server in 2 seconds. The server might be stuck or generating a slow response. - Django

Tags: python, django, selenium

I am getting this error with Django

```
RuntimeError: Failed to shutdown the live test server in 2 seconds. The server might be stuck or generating a slow response.
```

I am trying to run a simple test on a menu on my website. The menu is in an accordion style (scroll down to Example under the overview menu. An accordion is the thing in the Demo, where menus appear and disappear according to how you click them: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion#overview)

When one of the menus open, a text box for searching is present. What I'm trying to do is to press that button, then enter some values and click 'Enter' to go see the search results.

**CODE**

```
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time

class SeleniumTests(LiveServerTestCase):
    fixtures = ['testData.json',]

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.driver = WebDriver()
        super(SeleniumTests, cls).setUpClass()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        super(SeleniumTests, cls).tearDownClass()
        cls.driver.quit()

    def test_example(self):

        #load the site 
        self.driver.get('%s%s' % (self.live_server_url, '/testingDB/'))
        #find the accordion button
        elem1 = self.driver.find_element_by_id("search_button")
        #click it
        elem1.click()

        #wait a little bit so the accordion loads 
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        #could've also used this command ->time.sleep(1)

        #find the element that now appeared
        elem = self.driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        #enter the search query and press enter 
        elem.send_keys("selenium" + Keys.RETURN)
        #assert that a new page loaded, with Search in the title
        assert "Search" in self.driver.title
```

The test works great, but Django gives me the error. If I shorten the time too much, then selenium won't be able to find the search box, and it claims

```
Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

I don't know how to avoid the live test server error. (Django information obtained from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#django.test.LiveServerTestCase )

**Additional Information**

This is the menu:

*Part 1*

[image]

Then click 'Search' and the below appears in about 0.5 seconds.

*Part 2*
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error you are seeing is associated with the clean-up code found in `SeleniumTests.tearDownClass(cls)`. Within that method, if you call `cls.driver.quit()` before you call `super(SeleniumTests, cls).tearDownClass()` the error will go away.

Comment: If I do that I unfortunately get another error: `[Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`. However, when I do switch the two around, the browser closes, whereas before it didn't.

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: Everything works fine, the tests pass, the browser closes, but then it ends with this nasty `Connection forcibly closed` error =/.

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion pushed me to flip the two and try to find another solution :)

Comment: Thanks. The documentation was wrong in that issue and I reported your solution. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/#live-test-server

Answer (score 1):

I know my solution is not the correct way to do this, but this is what worked for me in the end:

First of all, I flipped the method calls in the tear down class, as suggested by diliop:

```
@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    super(SeleniumTests, cls).tearDownClass()
    cls.driver.quit()
```

However, this created another error: `[Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`. Everything worked fine, website closed, all tests passed, but this error appeared at the end.

I noticed that if I go to another page and try to close my website from that page (instead of the initial main page), the error disappears. So I put the following in the tearDown:

```
def tearDown(self):
    #go to main page
    self.driver.get('%s%s' % (self.live_server_url, '/testingDB/'))
    #find the first button
    elemOptionSet = self.driver.find_element_by_id("optionSetPage")
    #click it
    elemOptionSet.click()
```

Afterwards, when selenium tries to close the website, there are no errors. If anyone can explain this behavior, it would be great! But until then, this will do.