# Testing Django project, how can I avoid Errno 10054?

Tags: django, django-errors, django-dev-server

I'm testing a simple django project using its own development server. However every time I close my IE client an error appears in the console. It doesn't cause any failure though. When I open another IE browser client everything is normal.

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Which version of django are you using? Which of IE? [This bug report](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15178) mentions a similar problem when IE9 beta is used. The discussion suggests that the problem is solved in newer versions of django where the dev server is multithreaded (introduced in [version 1.4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#development-server-multithreading)).

Comment: You are using the runserver command, isn't? If you are, this is common and not a problem. You may see the error with the name "broken pipe error", in short is how the development server opens a connection to your browser and it doesn't finish to send all the output cause you stop it. there is no harm in here, if you are using a production webserver you will not see this error.

Answer (score 1):

**Django Debug Toolbar** generates tons of these errors. If you have it installed please try again without it

Answer (score 0):

> This happens when the client closes the connection before the server finished sending the data. If it only happens sometimes and is not a persistent problem ignore it.

Complete answer here → [Django development server broken pipe error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253288/django-development-server-broken-pipe-error)

Answer (score 0):

add refresh before quit,see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243267/django-and-selenium-web-testing-error-errno-10054)

```
    self.browser.refresh()
    self.browser.quit()
```