# ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host error with ChromeDriver Chrome Selenium Django

Tags: python, django, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am learning TDD by the "Obey the testing goat book", but I am trying to do it with Django 3.

If anyone knows it, I am at Chapter 6.

My code is:

```
class VisitorTest(LiveServerTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(2)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_starting(self):
        print(self.live_server_url) 

        self.browser.get(self.live_server_url)
```

and in console I am getting

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52187/devtools/browser/e9a03a04-819e-40a3-a0e4-bd4133d8f6cb
http://localhost:52180
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 52204)
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 52202)
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 52203)
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 654, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 654, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 364, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 364, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 724, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 724, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\Alex\PycharmProjects\goat\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 172, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\Alex\PycharmProjects\goat\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 172, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\Alex\PycharmProjects\goat\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\PycharmProjects\goat\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 654, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 364, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 724, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\Alex\PycharmProjects\goat\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\Alex\PycharmProjects\goat\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
----------------------------------------
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 8.779s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

However tests are running well (I didn`t displayed them here).

I made a research but didn`t found anything conclusive

Any idea why is displaying those and how to fix them?

Answer (score 3):

I've tried different suggested solutions unsuccessfully:

- [changing test server address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243267/django-and-selenium-web-testing-error-errno-10054) from "localhost" to "127.0.0.1"
- updating old ChromeDriver, 'cause my Chrome 83 is not officially supported by Anaconda's ChromeDriver 2.38
- adding `self.browser.refresh()` before calling `quit()` (as the book itself [suggest](https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/chapter_prettification.html#_static_files_in_django))
- using Edge browser (well... IE driver doesn't have this problem and I haven't tried FF)

If we look deeper this kind of errors is handled by `LiveServerTestCase.server_thread.httpd.handle_error` function which default implementation in `socketserver.BaseServer` just prints error messages to `stderr`. As these messages are harmless I've decided to suppress them.

```
import sys
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def suppress_stderr():
    "Temporarly suppress writes to stderr"
    class Null:
        write = lambda *args: None
    err, sys.stderr = sys.stderr, Null
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        sys.stderr = err

# Suppress stderr messages during quit process
with suppress_stderr():
    self.browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

...implies that the connection between the **ChromeDriver** and the **Browsing Context** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session was closed intermittemtly.

This issue is observed when **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using.

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v79.0.3945.36](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 79.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v79.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- (*WindowsOS only*) Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- (*LinuxOS only*) [Free Up and Release the Unused/Cached Memory in Ubuntu/Linux Mint](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html) before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### Reference

You can finda couple of relevant discussions in:

- [urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51799251/urllib3-exceptions-protocolerror-connection-aborted-error10054-an-exist/51799372#51799372)

Comment: I Lol'ed when I saw the current version of Selenium for this post!

Answer (score 1):

if you are using run_subprocess() make detach_mode=True and try it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).